# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources related to the English language
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/7606).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/10004/community-promotion-ads-2017)

Comment: @MartinSchröder It's probably not wise to mark a community post from a mod as a duplicate. Just a recommendation. This type of post isn't really subject to normal duplicate rules.

Comment: @Hank: It is; there is precedent. See e.g. [2015](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/5491/11394) & [2014](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4304/11394).

Comment: @MartinSchröder Touche. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 17):

[image: English Language Learners]

Comment: Based on [Earthliŋ's ad](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/7723/53935), with the new logo and a border to be eligible.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Explore the roots of English at the Latin Stack Exchange]

Comment: This image was discussed on [Latin SE's meta](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/207/12).  Feedback is certainly welcome!

Comment: Not good visually - too "busy" and quite hard to read at first glance. Try putting the background on an angle - say, 25 degree rotation clockwise - and ditch the shadowing on the main text. Alternatively (or, ideally, in addition), remove the words directly behind the main text - elicit, resurgent, verbatim, vapid, inchoate, moron, fluent, caveat, impinge, jejune).

Comment: @Chappo Thanks for the great feedback!  I've reduced the shadowing, added a slant, and did some rearranging.  Does this address your concern?  (incidentally, I find it easier to focus on the main text when it's 300px, rather than 600px).

Comment: Looks great! +1

Answer (score 11):

[image: Support the Literature SE on Area 51]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Come to Writer's Chat]

Comment: Image used in this ad is used by permission from the creator, Michele Maule, who has some really cool stuff for sale on [Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/shop/michelemaule?ref=pr_shop_more).

Comment: The image is delightful, but a bit dated [*c'est pas*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300015/are-there-any-fake-french-words-used-in-english)? I would have opted for a smart phone, an iPad, or a plain laptop. EL&U is,  after all, accessible only *online*

Comment: I shared this [on the RPG.SE meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/6027/4398) and was [told it probably doesn't follow the rules](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6024/community-promotion-ads-2016#comment17177_6027).

Comment: @BESW thanks, I'll make a new image. I guess I didn't understand the rule.

Comment: Isn't the apostrophe misplaced? Or is there really just *one* writer chatting? (I wouldn't normally nitpick something like this, but given that this is an ad *on EL&U* advertising a site *for writers*...)

Comment: +1; this ad is how I originally found the writing exercise in the Overlook Hotel. But maybe the image should be changed slightly to make clear that it's a regular *writing exercise* rather than just a writers' chat?

Answer (score 10):

[image: Wiktionary: Help write the free dictionary]

Answer (score 8):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/english.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Comment: Copied from last year; the size should not be a problem.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Comment: This is posted as an alternative to [the other answer linking to ELL](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/7628/160721) (which seems to suggest using the ELU ampersand). The text is based on the [old (2015) ad](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/7164/160721) and was redesigned to fit the new format.

Comment: The ad is double-size to be crisp even on Retina displays.

Comment: Needs a border around it to be valid. Also since ELL just got their new design, might consider using the logo update that as a good opportunity to  add the border.

Comment: @GraceNote Anyways, I think this is useful, because asking about English *syntax* should be done there, instead of here instead.

Comment: Derivative version, based on this one: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/9401/53935

Comment: Umm... this does not redirect to ELL.SE, it is an imgur link.

Comment: @Constant'sErik Wasn't me, but it should work now.

Comment: @Earthliŋ I know it wasn't you, but, the problem was still a serious problem. Now it works.

Comment: Wow. Such blurry.

Comment: @curiousdannii I guess I'd better redo it, then?

Answer (score 5):

[image: Language Learning Stack Exchange]

Comment: That either *is*, or is disturbingly similar to, Comic Sans. In which case, this ad needs to be burned with fire.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Comic Neue :)

Comment: *burns with fire*

Answer (score 3):

[image: Commit to the Internet of Things Q&A]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Language Learning Stack Exchange]

Answer (score -7):

[image]

Comment: Can you change "for" to "about", and maybe we should suggest people trying to learn English, specifically, go to ELL rather than the more general LL? Otherwise, I've already cast my +1.

Comment: It should be "....*ask about* the language itself". You ask *for something*, if you want to receive it.

Comment: The text doesn't make much sense. "This site" - EL&U (the place you read the ad) or LL (the place you're advertising)? "Language Learning is" - meaning LL * is * (in the way the universe * is *), or LL is the place to ask for the language itself? The confused language is not a good advertisement for a language site.

Answer (score -10):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: In previous years there has been a competition to see which site can downvote their twitter ads the most. Let's join in!