# ELL ad is out of date

Tags: support, status-completed, ell

The ad for English Language Learners has the old speech bubble with ELL in it, instead of the new picture. Will you update it?

[Here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7606/community-promotion-ads-2016/7723#7723) is the answer on the Promotional Ads 2016 post.

Comment: I think we can do that by changing the image in the meta post. If someone gets a chance to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ELL community ad has now been updated, and should now match the site’s graduation theme.

Comment: Is the ELL ad meant to link through to ELL? It doesn't. It links to the image itself. Is this fixable? (I'm using Firefox 48 on windows 10)